# Issue while Creating Database project

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014

I am trying to create a database project using VS 2013 professional with SQL Server 2014 Express, I am receiving below error

[image]

Note: I am trying to create script files for existing database. Would the database project work on 2014 Express SQL Server?

I am guessing the problem is "The target platform for the Database project being SQL Server 2012". If this is correct how to set the target platform for SQL Server 2014?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Folks,

I researched quite a bit and found the answer to this problem myself :)

Visual Studio 2013 now has an update that adds SQL Server 2014 support under **Tools –> Extensions and Updates –> Updates**

After installing the update under **Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio** I see I now have **SQL Server Data Tools 12.0.40403.0**

Now **SQL Server 2014** is an option in my database project settings and everything works!